# SharePoint 2013 unable to co-author

Tags: 2013, co-authoring

lately, I am unable to co-author the power point slide in SharePoint 2013.

the error shows

> The file is locked but it was not locked by any users.

what could be the issues?

Comment: is the file checked out by someone? or open by anyother use?